# Does BigCommerce have any restriction on number of API calls made from one API key or store?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

We have an application which pulls store details like store order details & products,

So there are chances that some stores may have 20K orders or more.

So i just wanted to know about the maximum call limit for each API, so that i can handle it from my side when limit is reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a reply from BigCommerce Support,

`The 20k requests/hour limit is for the store and is shared amongst all API keys for a given store.`

Answer (score 0):

This has now changed, the Platinum Package gets 60K requests and the enterprise level accounts are unlimited.